# How to git format-patch for all but first commit

Tags: git

I often have a source tree that did not originate as a git repository.  Typically before I begin making changes I add a local git repository.  My first commit is invariably a snapshot of the starting state of the tree.

From that point on I create regular commits.  Periodically I need to convey my work elsewhere as a series of patches.  To do so I want to create patches for all but my very first commit (since that first commit is typically enormous and conveys no useful information).

Is there an easy way to do this without knowing *a priori* the number of commits in my branch?

Comment: To edit last commit type git commit --amend

Comment: Why are you using patches to share your work rather than sharing a branch?

Comment: Using git is a person preference.  I use it was much for grooming a set of commits for review as for recording blow by blow history.  Those with whom I am collaborating are not git savy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider tagging your initial state, before making your commits.

Then a patch would be [as simple as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002164/6309):

```
git format-patch myTag..HEAD --stdout > changes.patch
```

The tagged initial commit would not be part of that patch.

If you don't want just one patch, [count the commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998123/6309):

```
count=$(($(git rev-list --count myTag..HEAD) - 1))

git format-patch -${count}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  You supplied two key items:

* tag the initial commit (I can script this)

* how to count the number of revisions (I do want multiple patches)