# Git create full file patches to download/distribute?

Tags: git

Either i'm going nuts or nobody likes/liked this feature, but a long time ago i used to use subversion with sourceforge system. I had the ability to create full file patches for commits done.

I cannot figure out anyway to create these in git, all i want is the files that were changed from XX commit and only those files in their entirety so that i could hand them off to someone/upload just those files to a location.

As it currently stands i'm stuck reuploading the entire project because i have nothing that tells me what was changed. Since we're also on a shared web host there is no way to get git on the server without upgrading to more expensive package.

I've tried

```
git archive --output=/home/username/temp.zip <commit id>
```

which put everything into a zip nicely but it did just that, it put everything. Also tried a variation of format-patch but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that I misunderstood what you wanted in my other answer.  `git archive` can take a list of paths to include in the archive, so you could do:

```
git archive -o /tmp/foo.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only oldcommit HEAD)
```

If your filenames contain surprising characters, though, it would be safer to do:

```
git diff -z --name-only oldcommit HEAD | xargs -0 git archive HEAD -o /tmp/blah.zip --
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In my case I needed it again a branch instead of commit. So I did: `git diff -z --name-only origin/branch_name | xargs -0 git archive HEAD -o /tmp/blah.zip`, and then applied those changes by extracting file in my repo: `tar -xf /tmp/blah.zip`

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to try would be to save the output of `git diff`, which might be sufficient in your situation:

```
git diff oldcommit > test.patch
```

If you have changed binary files since then, you could try:

```
git diff --binary oldcommit > test-with-binaries.patch
```

In that case you'd then need to apply the patch with `git apply`.  Otherwise, I would create a new branch based on `oldcommit`, do a squashed merge from `master`, commit the result and and use `git format-patch` to produce the patch.  That method (and several other solutions to your problem) are described in more detail in the answers to this similar stackoverflow question: [How do you squash commits into one patch with git format-patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616556/how-do-you-squash-commits-into-one-patch-with-git-format-patch)

Comment: That still only outputs the section that was changed, i need the whole files in their entirety. If i changed 2 lines on config.inc i want the entire config.inc not just the changed lines.

Comment: @iarp: Ah, OK - sorry.  I've added another answer with a different suggestion that uses `git archive` instead.