# How to prevent git format-patch from truncating filenames

Tags: git

I use git format-patch to share a list of patches for code review with my team members. The problem is I sometimes have quite a long commit message, and git format-patch truncates them when generating the files.

For example, I'd like to have a patch named 001-My-complete-message-bla-bla-bla.diff, but I get something like 001-My-comp.diff which doesn't help much understanding what there is inside.

I've searched everywhere about it for hours but I can't find any answer. It would be curious that no option exist to manage this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've came across the same issue,  `git format-patch`   take the object line as the name of the patch file and truncates it. Is there any options  could change the default behavior of `git format-patch` ?

Answer (score 2):

9 years later, there seems to be a solution (compared to [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665132/6309)) with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

The maximum length of output filenames "[`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/473c6224c6e46b68c4765d56628a85cea0ee9985/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> creates has become configurable (used to be capped at 64).

See [commit 3baf58b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3baf58bfb4bcfe201970abeffa8e1396d2324250) (06 Nov 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 473c622](https://github.com/git/git/commit/473c6224c6e46b68c4765d56628a85cea0ee9985), 21 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3baf58bfb4bcfe201970abeffa8e1396d2324250): make output filename configurable

> For the past 15 years, we've used the hardcoded 64 as the length limit of the filename of the output from the "[`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3baf58bfb4bcfe201970abeffa8e1396d2324250/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> command.
>
> Since the value is shorter than the 80-column terminal, it could grow without line wrapping a bit.
> At the same time, since the value is longer than half of the 80-column terminal, we could fit two or more of them in "`ls`" output on such a terminal if we allowed to lower it.
>
> Introduce a new command line option `--filename-max-length=<n>` and a new configuration variable `format.filenameMaxLength` to override the hardcoded default.
>
> While we are at it, remove a check that the name of output directory does not exceed `PATH_MAX---this` check is pointless in that by the time control reaches the function, the caller would already have done an equivalent of "`mkdir -p`", so if the system does not like an overly long directory name, the control wouldn't have reached here, and otherwise, we know that the system allowed the output directory to exist.
> In the worst case, we will get an error when we try to open the output file and handle the error correctly anyway.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3baf58bfb4bcfe201970abeffa8e1396d2324250/Documentation/config/format.txt#L97-L101):

> ### `format.filenameMaxLength`
>
> The maximum length of the output filenames generated by the
> `format-patch` command; defaults to 64.
> Can be overridden by the `--filename-max-length=<n>` command line option.

`git format-patch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3baf58bfb4bcfe201970abeffa8e1396d2324250/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L204-L210):

> ### `--filename-max-length=<n>`
>
> Instead of the standard 64 bytes, chomp the generated output
> filenames at around '`<n>`' bytes (too short a value will be
> silently raised to a reasonable length).
> Defaults to the value of the `format.filenameMaxLength` configuration
> variable, or 64 if unconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no solution on the format-patch front, one possible workaround would be to make an **[incremental bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860166/how-to-synchronize-two-git-repositories/4860455#4860455)**, which:

- would result in only one file (instead of [many for the patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616556/how-do-you-squash-commits-into-one-patch-with-git-format-patch))
- would support a kind of `git log` with `git bundle verify`: it will list the commits included in that bundle, with their (complete!) log message

---

[Abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern) suggests a temporary branch for applying and examining those patches before merging back to their own branch.
That is a possibility, but still, log messages are nice ;)

Comment: Another suggestion is that the team members man up, apply the patches to a temporary branch and use the available git tools to see what the changes are before merging/rebasing/cherry-picking the changes they want back into their own branches :)

Comment: @Abizern: true. I have included your comment in the answer.

Comment: Actually the filename is not really an issue in the process because we upload our patch files to a code review tool named Crucible which allows to check the modifications and comment it.

But as I'm curious, and like to store files with a meaningfull name, I often take some time to rename by hand files generated by git format-patch. I'm then looking for any method quicker than manual rename of a few patches.

Comment: @vbourdeix: I have Crucible (Atlassian FishEye/Crucible), but it is a generic user on Crucible side which does the polling, instead of me having to upload anything.