# Git commit patches

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there a way to export a sequence of commits into a patch from Git. Say I need to export the last 5 commits from a repository and import them into another repository. How would I go about doing that?

Help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616556/how-do-you-squash-commits-into-one-patch-with-git-format-patch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git format-patch` is designed for that purpose:

```
git format-patch --stdout HEAD~5 > ~/patches
```

The output is a readable BSD-mailbox-style file that contains patches along with some metadata such as the commit messages. To import the patches into the other repository, use `git am`:

```
git am < ~/patches
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the help. Everything works well except when I try to import the patch I get the error "Patch format detection failed.". Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Can you post the exact `git format-patch` and `git am` commands you are using to export and import the patches? (Edit the question if necessary.) Also, are you sure that the patch file didn't get corrupted on the way, if you are transferring it by email or such?

Answer (score 1):

You can select any range you want with format-patch

```
git format-patch --stdout R1..HEAD > output.patch
```