# git format-patch query

Tags: git, patch, format-patch

I am trying to create a patch through git between master and my working branch.
I used following command:
`git format-patch master..workingbr`
But it is creating incremental patches for all the intermediate commits. I wanted to create a single patch for the difference between master branch and current working branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616556/how-do-you-squash-commits-into-one-patch-with-git-format-patch seems similar

Comment: Thanks. Creating a branch is the only solution? can't it be done without it?

Comment: yes squashing your commits on a *throwaway* branch is better in order to generate your patch from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the man page - `git format-patch` - Prepare each commit with its patch in *one file per* commit,..

So, if you want a single patch, you do need to create a single commit that squashes your series together, probably on a separate branch, as per VonC's comments.