# Create git patch from specific commits

Tags: git, format-patch

Let's say you have commits on Branch A:

```
1
2
3X
4
5X
6
7
```

And you want to create a patch from commits 1,2,4,6. I think it's possible using 3 patches:

```
git format-patch -2 3X --stdout > first.patch
git format-patch -1 5X --stdout > second.patch
git format-patch -1 7  --stdout > third.patch
```

But is it possible using a single patch?

Comment: especially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1892773/2082964

Comment: yes quite similar but I don't want commits 3X and 5X to be inside a single patch

Comment: you're right; that is different. I retracted my close vote. I don't have an idea... other than `cat first.patch second.patch third.patch > one.patch`

Comment: If 3X and 5X commits are only on different files than 1,2,4,6 you can extract the changed file names and only diff them.