# How do you git patch while saving multiple commit messages?

Tags: git

I have 4 commits that I want to save to one patch but I want to keep the 4 commit messages.

I've followed this solution but it doesn't save the separate commit messages:
[How do you squash commits into one patch with git format-patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616556/how-do-you-squash-commits-into-one-patch-with-git-format-patch)

Comment: Which answer did you follow?  I believe `git format-patch master --stdout > my_new_patch.diff` should work

Comment: Why not generate 4 patches with `git format-patch`, apply them and then use `git rebase -i` to adjust everything to your needs?